# Strange relations between objects

Tags: modeling

In my scene there are some objects that are somehow connected to each other. E.g. if I transpose one object called 'Body' it also moves the object 'Border'. 
[image]

The movement of 'Border' is not linear to 'Body'.
I removed all groups, constraints, parenting etc. of all objects. So I can not see any relationship between the objects. Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing the file it's hard to tell for sure, but if you checked everything else, then it lefts only driver, although it's a wild guess.

Comment: I did not find a good solution to upload .blend files somewhere.. I hoped that the solution to the problem would be obvious. Drivers should be highlighted in the transform location field or seen in the graph editor as far as I know. But there seems to be no driver.

Comment: Then I have no clue.Hopefully someone had similar case and will give the right answer. For sharing .blend files [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) is a good way to go.

Comment: @LucaHofmann Blend files can be uploaded [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and then embedded in your question.

Comment: I did not know Blend-Exchange.. thank you :) I need to remove everything else in my .blend file before I upload it. Maybe it's a solution to export the objects as .obj files and re-import them. I'll try that first.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. there was no relation in the scene. The problem was that I somehow enabled the **'Proportional editing object mode'** (Shortcut: O). I did not know this option in object mode. Thank you for the answers and sorry wasting your time.
It still do not get why objects that are closer to 'Body' did not move but only 'Border'...

Comment: I've just read this on Sunday 23/10/2016.  A very similar thing happened to me only today,.    Guess what?  It was that bloomin' Prop-edit button!  ha ha  Got pressed along the way somewhere!